# Cauchy-Hadamard formula example

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence of the following power series:

$$1 + 3z + 2z^2 + 9z^3 +...+ 2^nz^{2n} + 3^{n+1}z^{2n+1}.$$

Attempt: I've tried using the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, to get: 
$$\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \text{ } (2^nz^{2n} + 3^{n+1}z^{2n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}},$$ 
but I don't know what to do from here. I thought factoring out the $z^{2n}$ might help, to get 
$$\frac{1}{R} = z^2 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \text{ }(2^n + 3^{n+1}z)^{\frac{1}{n}},$$ 
but this appears to be useless.

The answer key I have says that $R = 1/ \sqrt{3},$ and mentions that the terms of even index do not contribute to the answer. Can anyone shed any light on this? It's possible I've totally misinterpreted the formula. Anyway, thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, what book is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hadamard's formula* directly gives  $\;\dfrac1R=\limsup\, \lvert a_n\rvert^{\tfrac1n}$, and there are two sorts of $\lvert a_n\rvert^{\tfrac1n}$:
$$\begin{cases}\lvert a_{2p}\rvert^{\smash{\tfrac1{2p}}}=2^{1/2},\\
\lvert a_{2p+1}\rvert^{\tfrac1{2p+1}}=3^{\tfrac{n+1}{2n+1}}\to 3^{1/2}.
\end{cases} $$
Hence $\;\dfrac1R=\limsup\, \lvert a_n\rvert^{\tfrac1n}=\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. Do you know why it is that in the ratio test, you \it{include} the $z$ variable in the computation (ie. when you look at $\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|$), whereas in the C-H test you don't?

Comment: The *reasoning* to establish Cauchy-Hadamard formula includes $z$, since $R$ is the least upper bound of  $z$ such that $\lvert z\rvert \,\lvert a_n\rvert^{\tfrac1n}<1$. From this observation, one deduces the actual formula.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The sequences $(\left|2^nz^{2n}\right|)$ and $(\left|3^{n+1}z^{2n+1}\right|)$ must be bounded, which gives $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: Could you possibly expand on this answer? I take it that you are applying C-H to each term separately. Doing this, I get $\frac{1}{R} = 3|z|^2$ (for the second term). Do you just conclude the answer from this?

Comment: No. I use the fact that if $|z|<R$, the series $\sum a_nz^n$ converges absolutely, and if $|z|>R$, the sequence $(a_nz^n)$ is not bounded.