# Calculate $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[k]{k(k+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How do I calculate the following limit: $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[k]{k(k+1)}$

The only limit identity that I know which closely resembles this is $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[k]{k}=1$.

**Edit:** This question came in context of finding the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^k z^{2k}}{k^2+k}$.

**Attempt:** Clearly, the ratio test here is inconclusive. So, I tried Cauchy-Hadamard Formula.

For the general form of a power series, this says that $R=\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}$.

But now $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{\dfrac{2^k}{k^2+k}}=2 \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{\dfrac{1}{k^2+k}}=2$ as per the calculations done by @gimusi, @Key Flex.

**Doubt:** The answer at the back of the book gives $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$ \sqrt[k]{k(k+1)}= \sqrt[k]{k} \,\sqrt[k]{k+1} \to 1 \cdot 1=1$$

indeed

$$\sqrt[k]{k+1}=e^{\frac{\ln k}{k+1}}\to e^0=1$$

and more in general for any polynomial $p_n(k)$ we have

$$\sqrt[k]{p_n(k)} \to 1$$

by the same proof.

Comment: How does this help? What is $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{k+1}$? Equivalently, what is  $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{1+\frac{1}{k}}$

Comment: How do you evaluate $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[k]{k}=1$?

Comment: @user330477 We have $\sqrt[k]{k+1}=e^{\frac{\log k}{k+1}}$? Does the $+1$ change something?

Comment: @user330477 The key fact is that when k is large the "+1" is completely negligeble.

Comment: I proceeded like Key Flex and got stuck on how to evaluate $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Comment: Note that $$(1+\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{k}}$$ is in the form $1^0$ which is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: Does this mean the limit is trivially $1$?

Comment: @user330477 Yes exactly.

Comment: @user330477 It should be better if you show your full work in the question in order to avoid downvoting and closure.

Comment: I edited the question to make the context clear.

Comment: @user330477 That’s much better now! The limit isbthen 1 and you obtain the given result!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85314/discussion-between-user330477-and-gimusi).

Comment: @user330477 Sorry I don’t look that, I was focused on the limit. You have a $z^{2k}$ term, maybe the problem is here.

Comment: You can always use the Cauchy-Hadamard formula and then it suffices to find the desired limit in question.

Comment: @user330477 Yes but you need to consider $|z^2|<\frac1R$. The limit is not the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Refer to the statement and the proof [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Hadamard_theorem).

Comment: I still am not fully sure what you mean? But regardless, how should we got about doing this one?

Comment: @user330477 Refer also to the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2215747/505767)

Comment: I know fully understand what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @user330477 Take also a look to the example [here](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/MATH2962/r/PDF/tut06s.pdf) at page 2.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{k \to \infty}\root[{\large k}]{k\pars{k + 1}}} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{k \to \infty}
{\ln\pars{k\bracks{k + 1}} \over k}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{k \to \infty}{\ln\pars{\bracks{k + 1}\bracks{k + 2}} -
\ln\pars{k\bracks{k + 1}} \over \bracks{k + 1} - k}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\ 
\exp\pars{\lim_{k \to \infty}\ln\pars{1 + {2 \over k}}} =
\bbx{\large 1}
\end{align}

> In expression \eqref{1}, I used the
>   [Stolz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{a_k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ if the second limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[k]{k(k+1)}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}((k^2+k)^{\frac1k})=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(k^2\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)\right)^{\frac1k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)^{\frac 1k}\cdot k^{\frac2k}=1\cdot1=1$$

Comment: You forgot the $\frac{1}{k}$ over $1+\frac{1}{k}$. This limit is what is causing me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @user330477 I factored out $k^2$ from $k^2+k$, my computation is correct

Comment: No, your computation is not correct. The $\frac{1}{k}$ power should also be over $1+\frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: @user330477 see the double parentheses, $(())$. It means $1+\dfrac1k$ is also included

Comment: Until those (()) everything is correct. What I meant was the equality after that.

Comment: @KeyFlex You lost an exponent here $$\ldots=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)^{\color{red}{\frac1k}}\cdot k^{\frac2k}=1\cdot1=1$$

Comment: @gimusi Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

$(k)^{1/k}(k+1)^{1/(k+1)} \lt $

$(k(k+1))^{1/k} \lt$

$ (k)^{1/k}(2)^{1/k}(k^{1/k}).$

Take the limit.